# Multiple "WHERE" conditions in a "NOT EXISTS" clause for distance bound checking

Tags: postgis

My dataset consists of several area id's. Each "area id" can have multiple clusters. For each cluster, I want to check if any of the imei's belonging to that "area id" have been in a 20m proximity or not. Specifically, I want to identify clusters where the proximity has been 20 m or greater.

Would the conditions other than the "ST_DWithin" be checked correctly in order to achieve this task?

Here is my code:

```
explain with imei_clustered as (select a."IMEI",a2."ID" as area_id_ from campaign_area_assets caa 
left join assets a on a."ID" = caa."assetID"
left join area a2 on a2."ID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID" 
left join area_type at2 on at2."ID" = a2."areaTypeID"
where 


a2."ID" in ('d99e11ab-e952-4f02-a31e-88500ba4a2ad',
'48a6f927-13fd-49cd-a448-e991d6a8584e',
'a6bbc83a-e464-4987-9c27-33d37531fbc2') 

--and

--a2."ID" in (select distinct areaID from campaign_scope)

and

at2."name" = 'Uc')
,


campaign_ping as not materialized (
select cp.*,caa."campaignScopeAreaID" as area_id_,cs."campaignStartDate" as campstart,cs."campaignEndDate" as campend from campaign_pings cp 
left join campaign_pings_validity cpv on cp."ID" = cpv."pingID"
left join assets on assets."IMEI" = cp.imei
left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = assets."ID" 
left join campaign_scope cs on cs."areaID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID" 
left join campaign_staff cs2 on cs2."campaignScopeID" = cs."areaID" 
left join staff_type st on st."ID" = cs2."staffTypeID" 
 
where cpv."isValid" = true
and cp.imei in (select distinct IMEI from imei_clustered)

and st.name = 'Team'

) 

,


clusters_raw AS (

    -- Select the cluster_id, convex_hull geometry, and calculate coverage

    select
    c.areaid,
    c.uc_name,
    c.cluster_id,
    c.convex_hull
FROM
    bfp_clusters_20_100_rad c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM campaign_ping cp
         
        where ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull::geography, cp."geoJson"::geography, 20)
        

        and 
(cp."generatedAt"::date between cp.campstart and cp.campend 
)
and cp.imei in (select imei from imei_clustered where imei_clustered.area_id_ = c.areaid)
  
        
        )
        )




-- Select and display the results from the 'clusters_raw' CTE

SELECT count(*) FROM clusters_raw;
```

Here is my query plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=583087449.29..583087449.30 rows=1 width=8)
  CTE imei_clustered
    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=18.00..105.61 rows=1 width=32)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17.71..105.23 rows=1 width=23)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12.87..24.51 rows=1 width=16)
                      Join Filter: (a2."areaTypeID" = at2."ID")
                      ->  Seq Scan on area_type at2  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=16)
                            Filter: ((name)::text = 'Uc'::text)
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on area a2  (cost=12.87..23.43 rows=3 width=32)
                            Recheck Cond: ("ID" = ANY ('{d99e11ab-e952-4f02-a31e-88500ba4a2ad,48a6f927-13fd-49cd-a448-e991d6a8584e,a6bbc83a-e464-4987-9c27-33d37531fbc2}'::uuid[]))
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "PK_4834f09d148bc9a0a2a506b1f66"  (cost=0.00..12.87 rows=3 width=0)
                                  Index Cond: ("ID" = ANY ('{d99e11ab-e952-4f02-a31e-88500ba4a2ad,48a6f927-13fd-49cd-a448-e991d6a8584e,a6bbc83a-e464-4987-9c27-33d37531fbc2}'::uuid[]))
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on campaign_area_assets caa_1  (cost=4.84..80.00 rows=72 width=23)
                      Recheck Cond: ("campaignScopeAreaID" = a2."ID")
                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_baa27c8ade8e5231dd1f31609a"  (cost=0.00..4.83 rows=72 width=0)
                            Index Cond: ("campaignScopeAreaID" = a2."ID")
          ->  Index Scan using "PK_2da8ab8bece3ae8da02e5bf1c93" on assets a  (cost=0.29..0.37 rows=1 width=23)
                Index Cond: (("ID")::text = (caa_1."assetID")::text)
  ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=819.13..583087331.09 rows=5038 width=0)
        ->  Seq Scan on bfp_clusters_20_100_rad c  (cost=0.00..292.41 rows=5041 width=326)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=819.13..115733.79 rows=352 width=47)
              Join Filter: (cs2."campaignScopeID" = cs."areaID")
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=818.04..114574.74 rows=49 width=79)
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=817.48..114236.52 rows=80 width=95)
                          Hash Cond: (caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = cs."areaID")
                          Join Filter: (((cp."generatedAt")::date >= cs."campaignStartDate") AND ((cp."generatedAt")::date <= cs."campaignEndDate"))
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=810.50..114227.65 rows=717 width=87)
                                Hash Cond: ((assets."ID")::text = (caa."assetID")::text)
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=479.05..113885.16 rows=1032 width=78)
                                      Hash Cond: ((cp.imei)::text = (assets."IMEI")::text)
                                      ->  Index Scan using gist_geog_cp_geojson on campaign_pings cp  (cost=0.55..113403.96 rows=1032 width=71)
                                            Index Cond: (("geoJson")::geography && _st_expand((c.convex_hull)::geography, '20'::double precision))
                                            Filter: ((SubPlan 2) AND (SubPlan 3) AND st_dwithin((c.convex_hull)::geography, ("geoJson")::geography, '20'::double precision, true))
                                            SubPlan 2
                                              ->  Unique  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                                                    ->  CTE Scan on imei_clustered  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                                            SubPlan 3
                                              ->  CTE Scan on imei_clustered imei_clustered_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                                                    Filter: (area_id_ = c.areaid)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=291.00..291.00 rows=15000 width=23)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on assets  (cost=0.00..291.00 rows=15000 width=23)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=201.20..201.20 rows=10420 width=23)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on campaign_area_assets caa  (cost=0.00..201.20 rows=10420 width=23)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=4.77..4.77 rows=177 width=24)
                                ->  Seq Scan on campaign_scope cs  (cost=0.00..4.77 rows=177 width=24)
                    ->  Index Scan using "PK_67c42d3c76ee09d085cf687e60c" on campaign_pings_validity cpv  (cost=0.56..4.23 rows=1 width=16)
                          Index Cond: ("pingID" = cp."ID")
                          Filter: "isValid"
              ->  Materialize  (cost=1.09..228.78 rows=1270 width=16)
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.09..222.43 rows=1270 width=16)
                          Hash Cond: (cs2."staffTypeID" = st."ID")
                          ->  Seq Scan on campaign_staff cs2  (cost=0.00..187.21 rows=7621 width=32)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1.07..1.07 rows=1 width=16)
                                ->  Seq Scan on staff_type st  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=16)
                                      Filter: ((name)::text = 'Team'::text)
JIT:
  Functions: 86
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Comment: As written, this can't be answered. You don't give an indication of the indexes available, of their selectivity, or the resulting query plan. The fact that this is a small CTE in a huge tangle of others means that the query in isolation might behave differently. You're asking us to guess when you already know what is necessary to find out.

Comment: @Vince I have added the complete code for context, and the resulting query plan as well.

Comment: The plan shows that it's using the spatial index and filtering by the `AND` parameter values. All conditions should always be checked correctly, so I don't understand the asked question.

Comment: @Vince I wanted to ask if the following condition in the final CTE

"and cp.imei in (select imei from imei_clustered where imei_clustered.area_id_ = c.areaid)" assures the following:

For each cluster, I want to check if any of the imei's belonging to that "area id" ONLY have been in a 20m proximity or not.